Do I need a different digital potentiometer? VDD is not isolated from VAB control
I recently got an AD5206 digital potentiometer, but perhaps due to my own negligence, I failed to realize the potentiometer voltage VAB = VDD, which means the device can not control the IO I want to interface to. Or that is my concern.
Not sure if this is the appropriate channel, but I am looking for a 50K ohm digital potentiometer with SPI control, which can have an isolated voltage on the potentiometers different from the IC source voltage, up to 24VDC.
Alternatively, might there be a workaround? I have a whole boat load of LM317 voltage regulators.
I've looked for 50K digital potentiometers, but haven't found anything that matches what I think I need. The application is to simulate NTC Thermistors connected to a PLC.

I'm not familiar with that model: what's "VAB"?
